# Не найден javac

Tags: java

Установила Java и JDK. Проверяю функционирование через cmd, пишет, что javac не найден. Path подключен. Три раза из-за этого переустанавливала, искала более новые версии. Ничего не помогает. Подскажите, что можно сделать? !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQtYI.jpg)!

Comment: Хорошо бы картинку вставить не ссылкой, а непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: cmd переоткрывали после установки?

Comment: Попробуй установить по [этой](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17CkmoxLxkqpRbJoeuk-mNzBy5RXpZril/view?usp=sharing) инструкции.<br>
Надеюсь у тебя нету проблем с украинским языком :)

Comment: `Program Files` без `x86`

Comment: Cmd переоткрывала. У меня на компе две папки «Program Files» и «Program files x 86». JDK и прочее хранится во второй.

Comment: @КсенияГринева это значит, что вы на 64-битную систему зачем-то установили 32-битную JDK. И ещё интересно, что у вас за сборка JDK, ведь Oracle перестал выпускать 32-битные версии ещё с Java9.